# Python - Parsing PDF Data into a Table Format

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, web-scraping

I am trying to duplicate the data found in the table within the PDF here: http://www.ct.gov/hix/lib/hix/CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_%28with_clarifications%29.pdf

My current code is pulling just the second page of the first table, which is page 11 (labeled page 2) in the document. Here is the code I am using:

```
import io, re
import PyPDF2
import requests

url = 'http://www.ct.gov/hix/lib/hix/CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_%28with_clarifications%29.pdf'

r = requests.get(url)
f = io.BytesIO(r.content)

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
contents = reader.getPage(10).extractText()

data = re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", contents).split()

csv = open('AWStest.csv', 'w')
csv.write(contents)
csv.close()
```

I am currently able to pull the data in a rough CSV format but have not been able to figure out how to parse the data to allow for me to store it to match the table it was scraped from. This is how it looks currently, with all spaced being line breaks in the CSV format:

ColElement
Data
Element
NameDate
ModifiedFormatLengthDescriptionElement
Submission
Guideline
Comments
Condition
(Denominator)
Recommended
Threshold
Member
Eligibility
DataContents
Guide
12/5/2013
3ME003Insurance
TypeCode/Product
4/1/2013Lookup
Table

Text
2Type
/Product
Identification
Code
Report
the
codethat
defines
the
type
ofinsurance
under
which
this
member's
eligibility
ismaintained.
EXAMPLE:
HM=HMO
Code
Description
9Self
pay
11Other
Non
Federal
Programs
*(use
ofthis
value
requires
disclosure
toDataManager
prior
tosubmission)
12Preferred
Provider
Organization
(PPO)
*13Point
ofService
(POS)
*14Exclusive
Provider
Organization
(EPO)
*15Indemnity
Insurance
*16Health
Maintenance
Organization
(HMO)
Medicare
Risk
(Use
toreport
Medicare
PartC/Medicare
Advantage
Plans)*
17Dental
Maintenance
Organization
(DMO)
*96Husky
Health
A97Husky
Health
B98Husky
Health
C99Husky
Health
DAMAutomobile
Medical
*CHChampus
(now
TRICARE)
*DSDisability
*HMHealth
Maintenance
Organization
*LMLiability
Medical
*MAMedicare
PartA*(Medicare
Feefor
Service
only)
MBMedicare
PartB*(Medicare
Feefor
Service
only)
MCMedicaid
*MDMedicare
PartDOFOther
Federal
Program
*(use
ofthis
value
requires
disclosure
toDataManager
prior
tosubmission)
TVTitle
V*VAVeterans
Affairs
Plan
*WCWorkers'
Compensation
*ZZMutually
Defined
*(use
ofthis
value
requires
disclosure
toDataManager
prior
tosubmission)
All96.0%

This sample data represents the header rows and the first line of data. I have been able to break up the words based on capitalization, but unfortunately it breaks up the fully capitalized words into individual letters as well. I used this code:

```
fcsv = open('AWStest.csv', 'r')

for line in fcsv.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    line.split('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*')
    print(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', line))
```

I need help figuring out the best way to reproduce this full table in a format that will allow me to load it into a NoSQL database and query the individual row's requirements to produce reports. What is the best way to add to my code in order to do this? Is there a better way to go about scrapping the PDF in a more accurate format?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like having the position of the text on the page would help you greatly. I recommend using [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to extract the text with position data so you can find a row.

Here's a code sample to get a *.csv file of text with positions. That can get you started on mining the information with Python hopefully.

```
#!python3.3
""" Use PyMuPDF to extract text to *.csv file. """
import csv
import json
import os
import sys

import fitz

assert len(sys.argv) == 2, 'Pass file name as parameter'

srcfilename = sys.argv[1]
assert os.path.isfile(srcfilename), 'File {} does not exist'.format(srcfilename)

dstfilename = '{}.csv'.format(srcfilename)
with open(dstfilename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', newline='') as dstfile:
    writer = csv.writer(dstfile)
    writer.writerow([
        'PAGE',
        'X1',
        'Y1',
        'X2',
        'Y2',
        'TEXT',
    ])
    document = fitz.open(srcfilename)
    for page_number in range(document.pageCount):
        text_dict = json.loads(document.getPageText(page_number, output='json'))
        for block in text_dict['blocks']:
            if block['type'] != 'text':
                continue
            for line in block['lines']:
                for span in line['spans']:
                    writer.writerow([
                        page_number,
                        span['bbox'][0],
                        span['bbox'][1],
                        span['bbox'][2],
                        span['bbox'][3],
                        span['text'],
                    ])
    document.close()
```

Here's some code I wrote to mine your PDF and get things into a *.csv file that is better formatted:

```
#!python3.3
import collections
import csv
import json
import os

import fitz  # PyMuPDF package


class MemberEligibility(object):

    """ Row in Member Eligibility Data Contents Guide table. """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize object. I've made all fields strings but you may want some to
        be dates or integers.
        """
        self.col = ''
        self.element = ''
        self.data_element_name = ''
        self.date_modified = ''
        self.fmt = ''
        self.length = ''
        self.description = ''
        self.comments = ''
        self.condition = ''
        self.recommended_threshold = ''


def get_sorted_list(document, page_number):
    """
    Get text on specified page of document in sorted list. Each list item is a
    (top-left y-coordinate, top-left x-coordinate, text) tuple. List sorted
    top-to-bottom and then left-to-right. Coordinates converted to integers so
    text with slightly different y-coordinates line up.
    """
    text_dict = json.loads(document.getPageText(page_number, output='json'))
    text_list = []
    for block in text_dict['blocks']:
        if block['type'] == 'text':
            for line in block['lines']:
                for span in line['spans']:
                    text_list.append((
                        int(span['bbox'][1]),  # Top-left y-coordinate
                        int(span['bbox'][0]),  # Top-left x-coordinate
                        span['text'],          # Text itself
                    ))
    text_list.sort()
    return text_list


def main():
    # Downloaded PDF to same folder as this script
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    pdf_filename = os.path.join(
        script_dir,
        'CT_DSG_-12132014_version_1.2_(with_clarifications).pdf'
    )

    # Mine PDF for data
    document = fitz.open(pdf_filename)
    # Using OrderedDict so iteration will occur in same order as rows appear in
    # PDF
    member_eligibility_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    for page_number in range(document.pageCount):
        # Page numbers are zero-based. I'm only looking at p. 11 of PDF here.
        if 10 <= page_number <= 10:
            text_list = get_sorted_list(document, page_number)
            for y, x, text in text_list:
                if 115 < y < 575:
                    # Only look at text whose y-coordinates are within the data
                    # portion of the table
                    if 25 < x < 72:
                        # Assuming one row of text per cell in this column but
                        # this doesn't appear to hold on p. 10 of PDF so may
                        # need to be modified if you're going to do whole table
                        row = MemberEligibility()
                        row.col = text
                        member_eligibility_dict[row.col] = row
                    elif 72 < x < 118:
                        row.element += text
                    elif 118 < x < 175:
                        row.data_element_name += text
                    elif 175 < x < 221:
                        row.date_modified += text
                    elif 221 < x < 268:
                        row.fmt += text
                    elif 268 < x < 315:
                        row.length += text
                    elif 315 < x < 390:
                        row.description += text
                    elif 390 < x < 633:
                        row.comments += text
                    elif 633 < x < 709:
                        row.condition += text
                    elif 709 < x < 765:
                        row.recommended_threshold += text
    document.close()

    # Write data to *.csv
    csv_filename = os.path.join(script_dir, 'EligibilityDataContentsGuide.csv')
    with open(csv_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([
            'Col',
            'Element',
            'Data Element Name',
            'Date Modified',
            'Format',
            'Length',
            'Description',
            'Element Submission Guideline Comments',
            'Condition (Denominator)',
            'Recommended Threshold'
        ])
        for row in member_eligibility_dict.values():
            writer.writerow([
                row.col,
                row.element,
                row.data_element_name,
                row.date_modified,
                row.fmt,
                row.length,
                row.description,
                row.comments,
                row.condition,
                row.recommended_threshold
            ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You'll probably have to do a little more work to get exactly what you want.

Comment: So I am new to Python and have been asked to try and create a solution with no real background on the language, What would be the benefit to having the position if the amount of text in each cell can vary? I don't see how I would be able to dynamically pull the data and load it into a new DB with a similar structure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The x-coordinate of the text will tell you which column the text belongs to. The y-coordinate along with some logic will tell you which row the text belongs to. What is the structure of the DB you envision?

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate mining the PDF. Looks like the text in one column is sometimes part of the same text block as text in another column. You'll probably have to add some code to my example to get exactly what you want.